# C char * function problems

Tags: c, char

I need help, I'm just learning C, have no idea what is wrong:

Here I call `set_opts` function :

```
char * tmploc ;
tmploc=set_opts("windir","\\temp.rte");
printf(tmploc);
```

( I know , that printf is not formated, just used it for testing purposes)

function looks like this :

```
char * set_opts(char * env,char * path){
    char * opt;
    opt=malloc(strlen(env)+strlen(path)+1);
    strcpy(opt,getenv(env));
    strcat(opt,path);
    return opt;
}
```

Everything is ok, but when I try to call it again :

```
char * tmploc2 ;
tmploc2=set_opts("windir","\\temp.rte");
printf(tmploc2);
```

...program just terminates

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Check if `malloc` returns NULL and don't forget to `free` the memory you're allocating.

Comment: Please tell me when should I use free, thx

Comment: Use `free` at the point at which you will never refer to `tmploc2` in the future.

Comment: free (tmploc) solves this issue, however I need this in future, I have some parameters struct and I need to use set_opt few times

Comment: SOLVED,  after first use , I did :  free(set_opts);

Comment: it works, however I'm getting warn : warning: attempt to free a non-heap object

Comment: any ideas what should I do to fix this warning ?

Comment: You cannot free `set_opts`. That's a function. You can only free a pointer that was created by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: I removed it, and it is also working oO ,

Comment: probably this solved the issue :  malloc(strlen(getenv(env))+strlen(path)+1);

Comment: No, `free(set_opts)` does not ever work. And yes, what solved the issue is correcting your call to `malloc`. You have multiple answers that explained that. You should accept what you feel to be the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

You allocate the length of the string using `env`, but then populate it with `getenv(env)`.   If `getenv(env)` is longer than `env` then you have a good chance of a segfault. Did you mean to use `strlen(getenv(env))`?

You really ought to add some error checking to your code:

```
char *set_opts(char *env, char *path)
{
    char *opt;
    char *value;

    value = getenv(env);
    if (value == NULL)
      ... handle error
    opt = malloc(strlen(value)+strlen(path)+1);
    if (opt == NULL)
      ... handle error
    strcpy(opt,value);
    strcat(opt,path);
    return opt;
}
```

Comment: right, malloc(strlen(env)+strlen(path)+1);  is wrong , thanks

Answer (score 4):

Be careful  what you are doing with [`getenv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv), because:

> The getenv() function returns a pointer to the value in the environment, or NULL if there is no match.

So if you pass a name that does not correspond to an existing environment variable then you get NULL returned and that is going to kill your `strcpy(opt,getenv(env));`

I recomend:

1. Check what `malloc()` returns and make sure that it is non-null.
2. Check what `getenv()` returns and make sure that it is non-null.
3. As you pointed out, use a format string in your printf's and compile with `-Wall`.
4. Step through your code with a debugger to make sure it not terminating before you see the output.

Comment: I checked , these are env vars for sure.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason: malloc returns `NULL` and you never check for it. Same for getenv().
And it must be

```
 malloc(strlen(getenv(env))+strlen(path)+1);
```

If the actual contents of getenv("windir") is longer than 6 characters, you write past the malloced buffer, which invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of `getenv(env)`. Just put `strcpy(opt,env);`. `getenv()` is probably returning `NULL`.

Comment: OK, but that returns `"windir\\temp.rte"` which is not what is desired

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure:
    getenv(env)
will fit into "opt" ?
I  don't think so. And if it doesn't fit, then the strcpy could kill your program.

A correction:
    char * set_opts(char * env,char * path){
        char * opt;
        char * value = getenv(env);
        opt=malloc(strlen(value)+strlen(path)+1);
        strcpy(opt,value);
        strcat(opt,path);
        return opt;
    }

This way, you're sure you have enough space.

Comment: opt=malloc(strlen(getenv(env))+strlen(path)+1);